# Create image of all pages in pdf using mupdf library

Tags: android, native, mupdf

I am using mupdf to show pdf files stored in local repository of my android application. This is working quite well. Now i have to create a list that shows images of all pages of open pdf document and add a click event on every image that navigates the user to specific page. To work on this i want to know that in how many ways i can take a picture of every page of pdf document in my application.

Can i do this by running mupdf command directly in my android application or i have to work in mupdf.c file? Please put your views here. Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have a similar feature in our Android customizable magazine app, using muPDF: it is possible to display page thumbnails, and when you tap on a thumbnail, it brings you to the corresponding page.
This app is open source and available on [Github](https://github.com/libreliodev/android). It should be easy for you to review the code, and see how we implemented this feature.

Comment: Hi, I needed some help with MuPDF. It says that you need a minimum API level of 11. How did you make it run on Android 2.33 and below

Comment: can you please give the link of particular class where can you generate the images thumbnail from pdf in your code.

Comment: @user1806231 Looks like this is the class: https://github.com/libreliodev/android/blob/master/src/com/artifex/mupdf/PDFPreviewPagerAdapter.java

Comment: @Librelio please help regarding this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508322/fatal-error-fitz-h-no-such-file-or-directory-in-mupdf-library

Comment: Librelio please help regarding this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24545152/compiling-mupdf-lib-in-eclipse-cannot-unlink-nul-invalid-argument-android-nd