# Mupdf Generate Thumbnail

Tags: android, mupdf

I implemented E-Book App using Mupdf Library and want to generate thumbnail for each pdf file in my project
Could Anyone tell me how to generate This?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358461/create-image-of-all-pages-in-pdf-using-mupdf-library/15382454#15382454

Answer (score 5):

In Librelio they're using the old version of project muPDF without Cookie. In new versions you need to extend mu pdf core, like this:

```
class MuPDFThumb extends MuPDFCore{
    public MuPDFThumb(Context context, String filename) throws Exception{
        super(context, filename);
    }

    public Bitmap thumbOfFirstPage(int w, int h){
        PointF pageSize = getPageSize(0);
        float mSourceScale = Math.max(w/pageSize.x, h/pageSize.y);

        Point size = new Point((int)(pageSize.x*mSourceScale), (int)(pageSize.y*mSourceScale));
        final Bitmap bp = Bitmap.createBitmap(size.x,size.y, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        drawPage(bp,0,size.x, size.y, 0, 0, size.x, size.y,new Cookie());
        return bp;
    }
}
```

You need to extends, because Cookie is an internal class of MuPDFCore and it is required for  calling drawPage.

The method thumbOfFirstPage takes 2 arguments: width and height of the ImageView to fill with bitmap:

thumbnailImageView.setImageBitmap(bPGenerated) in UIThread

Comment: I was having the same problem with the internal class `Cookie`. Thanks to your comment now we know that we are forced to extend MuPDFCore

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
core.drawPage(bm, page, pageW, pageH, patchX, patchY, patchW, patchH);
```

Comment: Would you like explain more!?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to generate a thumbnail image of the first page for a PDF file, you can use the command line tool mudraw:

`mudraw -w 128 -h 128 -o thumbnail.png file.pdf 1`

Comment: sorry i want to generate it inside code to deal with it and display it in grid view

Comment: @BiboWagdy, just look at the source in `mudraw.c`.

Comment: Please when i press search button, search text box does not appear in portrait mode and it does not support arabic words for search